SQL Error [2290] [23000]: ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST_USER1.SYS_C008305) violated
CREATE TABLE Oracle_All_DataTypes (
    ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier
    FirstName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, -- First name must be provided
    LastName VARCHAR2(50), -- Last name is optional
    Age NUMBER(3) CHECK (Age BETWEEN 0 AND 120), -- Age must be between 0 and 120
    Email VARCHAR2(100) UNIQUE, -- Email must be unique
    PhoneNumber CHAR(10) CHECK (PhoneNumber LIKE '[0-9]%'), -- Must be 10 digits
    Salary NUMBER(10, 2) CHECK (Salary > 0), -- Positive salary
    JoiningDate DATE NOT NULL, -- Joining date is required
    IsActive CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' CHECK (IsActive IN ('Y', 'N')), -- Active status as 'Y' or 'N'
    DepartmentID NUMBER(5), -- Department ID
    Address VARCHAR2(255), -- Address
    City VARCHAR2(50), -- City
    State VARCHAR2(50), -- State
    Country VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'USA', -- Default country as USA
    PostalCode VARCHAR2(10) CHECK (LENGTH(PostalCode) BETWEEN 5 AND 10), -- Postal Code length check
    ManagerID NUMBER(10), -- ID of the manager
    CreatedDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- Record creation timestamp
    ModifiedDate TIMESTAMP, -- Record modification timestamp
    Gender CHAR(1) CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F', 'O')), -- Gender: Male, Female, Other
    Notes CLOB -- Notes can have a large amount of text
); 

The following is the Insert query
INSERT INTO Oracle_All_DataTypes (
    ID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Email, PhoneNumber, Salary, JoiningDate, 
    IsActive, DepartmentID, Address, City, State, Country, PostalCode, 
    ManagerID, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, Gender, Notes
) 
VALUES (
    1, -- ID
    'John', -- FirstName
    'Doe', -- LastName
    29, -- Age
    'john.doe@example.com', -- Email
    '1234567890', -- PhoneNumber (10 digits)
    75000.50, -- Salary
    TO_DATE('2024-01-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), -- JoiningDate
    'Y', -- IsActive
    101, -- DepartmentID
    '123 Elm Street', -- Address
    'Metropolis', -- City
    'NY', -- State
    'USA', -- Country
    '10001', -- PostalCode (5-10 characters)
    1001, -- ManagerID
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- CreatedDate
    NULL, -- ModifiedDate
    'M', -- Gender
    'Notes for this employee.' -- Notes
);


SQL Error [2290] [23000]: ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST_USER1.SYS_C008305) violated

I was trying to create a table with 20 columns with all Oracle data types with check constraints and was trying to insert data into the table but when I try to insert data into the table but it's showing error.

You haven't actually asked a question...

When adding an inline check constaint, you can use an alternative syntax to give it a name instead of letting the database auto-generate one for you. It's a bit of a hassle, but that way, when you violate a constant, it becomes much easier to understand where the problem is:
CREATE TABLE Oracle_All_DataTypes (
    ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier
    FirstName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, -- First name must be provided
    LastName VARCHAR2(50), -- Last name is optional
    Age NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT age_check CHECK (Age BETWEEN 0 AND 120), -- Age must be between 0 and 120
    Email VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE, -- Email must be unique
    PhoneNumber CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phonenumber_check CHECK (PhoneNumber LIKE '[0-9]%'), -- Must be 10 digits
    Salary NUMBER(10, 2) CONSTRAINT salary_check CHECK (Salary > 0), -- Positive salary
    JoiningDate DATE NOT NULL, -- Joining date is required
    IsActive CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' CONSTRAINT is_active_check CHECK (IsActive IN ('Y', 'N')), -- Active status as 'Y' or 'N'
    DepartmentID NUMBER(5), -- Department ID
    Address VARCHAR2(255), -- Address
    City VARCHAR2(50), -- City
    State VARCHAR2(50), -- State
    Country VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'USA', -- Default country as USA
    PostalCode VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT postalcode_check CHECK (LENGTH(PostalCode) BETWEEN 5 AND 10), -- Postal Code length check
    ManagerID NUMBER(10), -- ID of the manager
    CreatedDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- Record creation timestamp
    ModifiedDate TIMESTAMP, -- Record modification timestamp
    Gender CHAR(1) CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F', 'O')), -- Gender: Male, Female, Other
    Notes CLOB -- Notes can have a large amount of text
); 

After doing that, it's easy to see that the problem is with the PhoneNumber value:

ORA-02290: check constraint (SQL_EPXZNAEFQQHAYMFOYXNOYQNAX.PHONENUMBER_CHECK) violated ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

The problem is the usage of the like operator - from the comment, it looks like you're trying to use a regex, but that isn't how like works. The constraint literally means the value has to have the [0-9] sequence, followed by any sequence of characters (the %).
To achieve this functionality, you can use the regexp_like function:
CREATE TABLE Oracle_All_DataTypes (
    ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier
    FirstName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, -- First name must be provided
    LastName VARCHAR2(50), -- Last name is optional
    Age NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT age_check CHECK (Age BETWEEN 0 AND 120), -- Age must be between 0 and 120
    Email VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE, -- Email must be unique
    PhoneNumber CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phonenumber_check CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(PhoneNumber, '^[0-9]{10}$')), -- Must be 10 digits, validated with a regexp
    Salary NUMBER(10, 2) CONSTRAINT salary_check CHECK (Salary > 0), -- Positive salary
    JoiningDate DATE NOT NULL, -- Joining date is required
    IsActive CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' CONSTRAINT is_active_check CHECK (IsActive IN ('Y', 'N')), -- Active status as 'Y' or 'N'
    DepartmentID NUMBER(5), -- Department ID
    Address VARCHAR2(255), -- Address
    City VARCHAR2(50), -- City
    State VARCHAR2(50), -- State
    Country VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'USA', -- Default country as USA
    PostalCode VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT postalcode_check CHECK (LENGTH(PostalCode) BETWEEN 5 AND 10), -- Postal Code length check
    ManagerID NUMBER(10), -- ID of the manager
    CreatedDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- Record creation timestamp
    ModifiedDate TIMESTAMP, -- Record modification timestamp
    Gender CHAR(1) CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F', 'O')), -- Gender: Male, Female, Other
    Notes CLOB -- Notes can have a large amount of text
); 


Oracle's LIKE condition understands the % and _ wildcard characters, but not regular expression syntax. For that you need REGEXP_LIKE.
The equivalent of what you tried would be:
PhoneNumber CHAR(10) CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(PhoneNumber, '^[0-9]')), -- Must be 10 digits

But that is only checking the first digit is a number, not that there are only numbers, or exactly ten of them. For that you need to include anchors for the start and end of the string, and a count restriction:
PhoneNumber CHAR(10) CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(PhoneNumber, '^[0-9]{10}$')), -- Must be 10 digits

fiddle
You can query the user_constraints and user_cons_columns views to get the system-generated names of all your constraints, showing the conditions and which column each applies to, so you can match up the constraint name in the error message with the table/column it refers to, which will at least help to narrow down what is wrong in your insert statement.
fiddle with a deliberately wrong phone number to demonstrate.
But it is generally easier if you give constraints meaningful names, as shown in the documentation, which will usually give you enough of a clue in the error message to know what the issue is anyway, e.g.:
    PhoneNumber CHAR(10)
        CONSTRAINT ORA_ALL_DT_CK_PHONENUMBER
        CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(PhoneNumber, '^[0-9]{10}$')), -- Must be 10 digits

fiddle
